# how to create epoch list of dates

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using the code below to generate a list of dates in epoch. However, I am looking to have the most current date in the list equal to the value of unix_timestamp().

```
-- generate list of id's
with t1 as
(
select row_number() over (order by order_id) as n from orders 
limit 2000 
),
-- generate date based on incremental id's
t2 as 
(select 
  (getdate() - n+1) as date 
 from t1
)
  select 
    extract(epoch from date) as date
  from t2 
  where t2.date >= '2014-01-01'
  order by date desc
```

I am not sure how to get the last value in this list to be unix_timestamp()

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Do you just want a list of dates from 2014 to now? Will you be inserting it into a calendar table?

Comment: Hi John - Yes, just a list of dates in epoch (12 am each day) from 2014 till now but the last date should be epoch for unix_timestamp().  Wont be inserting in a table.

Comment: I'd also like to establish if getdate() is equivalent to unix_timestamp()

Answer (score 0):

Quotes around epoch using extract

```
select extract('epoch' from timestamp date) as date
from t2 
where t2.date >= '2014-01-01'
order by date desc
```

No quotes using date_part

```
select date_part(epoch, date) as date
from t2 
where t2.date >= '2014-01-01'
order by date desc
```